# How to change the arrowhead size in coreldraw?

Tags: vector, line-art, corel-draw

I was just adding arrowheads to a line in corldraw x6, and i realized that the arrowheads are too big for the concept i'm working on. But i cannot change the size of the arrowheads. if i try to scale the line, it just increases or decreases the length of the line, the size of the arrowheads remains constant.[[image: The arrowheads]]

[image: When i scale the line]

[image: The size of the arrowheads remains constant]

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the arrowhead, try with one you do not like, and modify it:

- Press F12
- Below the arrowhead press Options
- And you can choose New and change it

Or select one to modify and play with it.